# Elfeed - how to change database location?

Tags: elfeed

I found in elfeed-db.el code:

```
(defcustom elfeed-db-directory "~/.elfeed"
  "Directory where elfeed will store its database."
  :group 'elfeed
  :type 'directory)
```

but I don't know how/where to customize it. I need this, because i synchronize Emacs between computers.

Cheers

Kuba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: variable `elfeed-db-directory` is responsible for location of database and I set this via `setq` in `init.el` to my own location.